# Not able to create a project in Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Windows 10.

I am not able to create a new Blank App(Universal Windows) under Visual C++ Template in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Please check the snapshot of the error here:

[image: Visual Studio Project Error].

Also I check the list of Visual Studio software installed:

[image: Installed Visual Studio softwares]

I tried reinstalling also. But still the same error.

Please let me know if any one knows the fix.

Comment: What update of VS2015 are you running?  I don't see the required components to build UWP applications on your system

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.